# Default error page throw ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS or 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I have application which is ready to deploy but default error was working. 
For example if request with bad `action` name was

`http://localhost:44359/Home/Indexxxx`

the server response was

`http://localhost:44359/Home/Error?message=<error description>`

but now the server response is

`ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

but i think i did not change anything, where i can set this behavior ?

And also when it was working on `localhost`, it was not working at the server, because at the server application is putted into `folder` like

`http://IISURL/AppNameFolder/Home/Error?message=<error description>`

but the `server response error url` is still

`http://IISURL/Home/Error?message=<error description>`

without the `AppNameFolder` name and that address does not exist. Everything else is working fine.

Where i can manage this behavior ?

Comment: Something within your code is causing a redirect loop...

Comment: turn off custom errors and look if it still happens, or look for some code that makes redirection for example `global.asax`

Comment: ah thank you, I have `Response.Redirect()` in `Application_Error()` inside `global.asax` and because Redirect URL is static and wrong on different server, it cause loop.